# iOS app OpentOk library crashes with INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: opentok

We have an issue with iOS app stability. Our Application crashes inside the OpenTok library. It crashes inside the library and the stack trace does not contain any reference to the app code.

A list of last calls in the stacktrace:

```
[OTKitSessionDelegate otkitStreamCreated:]_block_invoke
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[_NSInlineData session:streamCreated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106044600


[OTKitSessionDelegate otkitSessionWillCloseSocket] + 3482407
Crashed: Thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000c202000c


[OTKitPublisherDelegate otkitPublisherStreamCreated:]_block_invoke
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
```

I'm using the latest version of OpenTok library 2.14.
Also, I've used different tools for monitoring the app if there are some thread synchronization or buffer overflow issues by using Address Sanitizer and Thread sanitizer and other xcode tools. No issues found.

Please assist with that. I will be very appreciate for any clue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are releasing the delegates without setting the OpenTok objects' delegates to nil.

Follow this order:

```
publisher.delegate = nil;
subscriber.delegate = nil; 
session.delegate = nil;
yourDelegate = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Looks like application reached out of memory after about 10 video sessions for 30 minutes. As a result it brings those crashes.